# How to set window position and make it unresizable in Go walk

Tags: user-interface, go

I am trying to figure out the basics of working with the Go GUI library, [walk](https://godoc.org/github.com/lxn/walk).

For starters, I would like to be able to

1. Control the **window's position**
   hopefully in a way similar to what other languages provide (center on screen, center to parent, exact coordinates etc).
2. Make the window **unresizable**

This is the code I have, I was hoping the `MaxSize` declaration would solve the second problem, but it doesn't, and I was looking for some sort of a `Position` declaration but couldn't find anything that makes sense to me.

```
package main

import (
    // "github.com/lxn/walk"
    . "github.com/lxn/walk/declarative"
)

func main() {
    MainWindow{
        Title:   "Test",
        MinSize: Size{300, 50},
        MaxSize: Size{300, 50}, // Doesn't work
        // Position: ...        // Doesn't exist
        Layout: VBox{},
        Children: []Widget{
            Label{Text: "Hello World"},
        },
    }.Run()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `walk` doesn't provide this functionality in its own API. However, `walk` created on top of [`win`](https://github.com/lxn/walk) which actually is just a Go bindings to WinAPI. So you can easily call any WinAPI functions. For example, to show a main window on a specified position one can call `SetWindowPos()`:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/lxn/win"
    "github.com/lxn/walk"
    . "github.com/lxn/walk/declarative"
)

const (
    SIZE_W = 600
    SIZE_H = 400
)

type MyMainWindow struct {
    *walk.MainWindow
}

func main() {
    mw := new(MyMainWindow)

    MainWindow{
        Visible: false,
        AssignTo: &mw.MainWindow,
    }.Create()

    defaultStyle := win.GetWindowLong(mw.Handle(), win.GWL_STYLE) // Gets current style
    newStyle := defaultStyle &^ win.WS_THICKFRAME                 // Remove WS_THICKFRAME
    win.SetWindowLong(mw.Handle(), win.GWL_STYLE, newStyle)

    xScreen := win.GetSystemMetrics(win.SM_CXSCREEN);
    yScreen := win.GetSystemMetrics(win.SM_CYSCREEN);
    win.SetWindowPos(
        mw.Handle(),
        0,
        (xScreen - SIZE_W)/2,
        (yScreen - SIZE_H)/2,
        SIZE_W,
        SIZE_H,
        win.SWP_FRAMECHANGED,
    )
    win.ShowWindow(mw.Handle(), win.SW_SHOW);

    mw.Run()
}
```

To make window unresizable you need to unset `WS_THICKFRAME` style, as shown in the example. More information can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx).